# How to load images from remote MySQL blob with a library like Picasso, Glide or Universal Image Loader?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-glide

I have a remote MySQL database, where there are the blobs of the images I want to load.

I've been trying to load them using Picasso, Glide or Universal Image Loader because my intention is to do it using threading and cache.

How can I do a POST request, sending the parameters by ($_POST in PHP) and receiving a JSONObject with the image encoded, and finally the library loads it into an imageview? Which is the best option?

For example, to pass a link with a php, and pass parameters in some way..:

```
String user_id = "0"; //Whatever

Picasso.with(this).load("http://myhost.com/load_image.php?id="+user_id).into(imageView);
```

My PHP returns a JSONObject with the string "image"= (image encoded in BASE 64).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok, I'll try it! Sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you use Glide, you can try creating a custom [ModelLoader](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/load/model/ModelLoader.html). You can implement your request inside the [DataFetcher](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/load/data/DataFetcher.html), parse the bytes of your image out of the JSOBObject and return an [InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html) containing data in your blob. You will probably want to create a custom data type, so Glide knows which ModelLoader to use:

```
JSONImageModel glideModel = new JSONImageModel(url);
```

Your model loader can then be registered for that type in your [GlideModule](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/module/GlideModule.html):

```
@Override
void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
    glide.register(JSONImageModel.class, InputStream.class, new JSONImageModelLoader.Factory());
}
```

Any requests for a model of your model type, will then be directed to your custom ModelLoader, which will fetch the data and pass it to Glide's existing decoders:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(new JSONImageModel(url))
    .into(imageView);
```

You can find more information about registering custom ModelLoader's on Glide's [configuration wiki page](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#lazily-apply-configuration-changes-using-glidemodules). Although it's aimed at downloading variable image sizes, there is also a [wiki page that describes creating a custom model loader](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Downloading-custom-sizes-with-Glide), which may be helpful.

Comment: Is there any example for this available? I am not able to understand how it can be done